# XML Output in Java -- what's with DOMImplementationLS?

Tags: java, xml, dom, w3c, ls

I just had to write the following stupid class to avoid going insane:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;

public final class XMLSerializer {
    public static final void writeDocument(Document input, OutputStream output) {
        try {
            DOMImplementationLS ls = 
                (DOMImplementationLS) DOMImplementationRegistry
                .newInstance().getDOMImplementation("LS");
            LSSerializer ser = ls.createLSSerializer();
            LSOutput out = ls.createLSOutput();
            out.setByteStream(output);
            ser.write(input, out);
        } catch (Exception e) { // DIAF Java
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Does this convenience method already exist in Java or a common library? It seems ridiculously long-winded, and that's even the version where all exceptions are collapsed under a "catch (Exception e)".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(input);
StreamResult resultStream = new StreamResult(output);
TransformerFactory transformFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
try {
    serializer.transform(domSource, resultStream);
} catch (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org/). It is an excellent XML library.